# Pass array to typeahead Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to pass via json an array of values to the `source:` option of Typeahead plugin of Bootstrap.

Here is my simple code: **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/toroncino/CKCJb/)**

I have a **JSON** object and I'd like to pass just the value id to the `source: array`

What I'm doing wrong... I tried many things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twitter's typeahead is expecting a Javascript array type. So, you'll need to convert your JSON object to a legitimate array using `JSON.parse(myJSONObject)`. However, typeahead is also expecting an array of strings, not array of arrays... So, the question is - which parameter of these arrays are you trying to show in the typeahead?

```
{
    "id":"2",
    "pid":"0",
    "type":"Group",
    "code":"g",
    "status":"1"
}
```

It looks like your `vals` function is isolating the `id` parameter. If that's the parameter you'd like typeahead to show, simply point `source` to `x`. Checkout this modified jsFiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/365Sf/

Comment: All you need to do is move this `var input = $('#test'); input.typeahead({ source: x });` to the bottom of the javascript code, and it should work for you.

Comment: This fiddle does not work for me on Chrome 46, canary.

Answer (score 2):

There is also the **local** property for this purpose.

You can use the **local** property in typeahead to provide an array without having to massage data.

e.g.

```
var data = ["john", "terry", "phil","stuart","louis","marie","bob"];

$("#user-search").typeahead({
   name: "user-search",
   local: data,
   limit: 10
});
```